# Calling specific UserControl dynamically created

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a set of UserControls dynamically created inside of a Panel with the following code

```
Dim X As Integer = 4
Dim Y As Integer = 0

For XRule As Integer = 0 To ArrayRuleNames.Length - 1
    Dim MyRule As New RuleControl
    Dim Location As Point
    Location.X = X
    Location.Y = Y
    With MyRule

        .RuleNameGpb.Text = ArrayRuleNames(XRule)
        .RuleNumberTxt.Text = ArrayRuleNumbers(XRule)
        .RuleNumberTxt.Tag = XRule
        .SendBtn.Text = "Read"
        .Parent = Me
        .Location = Location
        .Visible = True
    End With
    Panel.Controls.Add(MyRule)
    Y += 80
Next
```

Inside of every user control have some objects like Checkboxes and TextBoxes and I need to set to True o False the Checked property and write text on Text property from the main Form(WinForm).

So, I was thinking in to define a name in the code above and then call them by the name, Is this concept correct or I should do it in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the control a name:

```
With MyRule
  .Name = "MyRule1"
  .RuleNameGpb.Text = ArrayRuleNames(XRule)
  .RuleNumberTxt.Text = ArrayRuleNumbers(XRule)
```

then you can reference it:

```
If Panel.Controls.ContainsKey("MyRule1") Then
  Dim MyRule As RuleControl = Panel.Controls("MyRule1")
```